# First li how to make sticky header

Tags: html, css

```css
.list {
      li {
        &:first-child {
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
        }
      }
    }
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 180px;
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list li {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.list li span.category {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
   <li>
    <span class="category">Category 1</span>
    <span class="name">Item Title 1</span> 
    <span class="price">40 EUR</span>
    <span class="url"><a href="url1">Link to Article</a></span>
</li>   
<li>
    <span class="category">Category 2</span>
    <span class="name">Item Title 2</span> 
    <span class="price">55 EUR</span>
    <span class="url"><a href="url2">Link to Article</a></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to make fixed header and remaining li should be scroll. but it's happening. I have used 2 separate grid inside both first li should sticky. I don't want to use table and also this has horizontal scroll.

Comment: your question asking wrong format.
`list li:first-child span:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff; /* Added background color for visibility */
}`

Comment: Try this Code. In this code, li:first-child span:first-child targets the first span element inside the first li item in the list, and the position: sticky property makes it stick to the top of the page as the user scrolls down. The top: 0 property specifies that the element should stick to the top of its container element (in this case, the li element).